# DecimalFormat not ceiling properly

Tags: java, decimalformat, ceil

We are currently running some tests which involve ceiling numbers that have two decimal places. In order to achieve this, we are using Java's [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

However, the tests are getting strange results, particularly for the case when we wish to ceil up a **'0.00xxx'** number.

The following is the instance of the DecimalFormatter that is being used by the tests:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#########0.00");
    decimalFormatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

This test works as expected, that is, it was ceiled correctly:

```
//The below asserts as expected
    @Test
    public void testDecimalFormatterRoundingDownOneDecimalPlace3()
    {
        String formatted = decimalFormatter.format(234.6000000000001);
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected formatted number", "234.61", formatted);
    }
```

However, this does not:

```
//junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Unexpected formatted number 
//Expected :0.01
//Actual   :0.00

    @Test
    public void testSmallNumber()
    {
        double amount = 0.0000001;

        String formatted = decimalFormatter.format(amount);
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected formatted number", "0.01", formatted);
    }
```

**Can you please explain why we are getting this behaviour**. Thanks

EDIT:Another test as requested by comment. Still does not work.

```
//junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null
//Expected :0.01
//Actual :0.00

@Test
public void testStackOverflow() throws Exception
{
double amount = 0.0000006;
String formatted = decimalFormatter.format(amount);
Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected formatted number", "0.01", formatted);
}
```

I noticed that for it to work, a number greater than 0 must be within the range of the pattern. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: +1 removed my answer it's wrong :(

Comment: Try the same with 0.0000006. Whats the result?

Comment: It's because rounding does only consider one digit beyond the requested format. The number is truncated to `0.000` and then rounded to `0.00`. I'm not sure how to change that behavior, though.

Comment: @Bobby but the first test didnt consider the digit beyond the requested format. It read the last 1 and ceiled it.. =S

Comment: Whoops, then I'm outta the loop...

Comment: I've looked at this again, and [this simple and stupid test](http://pastebin.com/Y73SLedD) fuels my initial thought. Though, simply using `decimalFormatter.format(1 + amount)` instead yields the expected behavior. As long as the number is < 1 it seems to truncate one after a significant digit (was that English?).

Comment: If I understood correctly, youve spotted the same thing I did, that is, a number greater than 0 must be within the range of the pattern for it to work. This is not the behaviour that is expected!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. This code

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.0000001");
    bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    System.out.println(bd);
```

produces correct result

```
0.01
```